# Merge four loops 'for' in one with different inner methods

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop

I have four almost same loops in Java with different methods:

```
int Point;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    if (isLeft())
         Point = i;    
}

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    if (isRight())
         Point = i;
}

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    if (isAbove())
         Point = i;
}

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    if (isUnder())
         Point = i;
}
```

Can I merge all loops to one?

Comment: Yes you can, but at the moment, your loops have no effect as your `Point` variables are not visible outside the body of their loop.

Comment: Thanks, edited. And how it possible?

Comment: See solution of Mureinik.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not too sure what you are trying to do because all the conditions seem to change the value of point to the last value of the iterator that is 9.
but the snippet bellow can allow you to do so.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    if (isLeft())
        int Point = i;
    if (isRight())
        int Point = i;
    if (isAbove())
        int Point = i;
    if (isUnder())
        int Point = i;
}
```

another version of this will joint all the conditions

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (isLeft() || isRight() || isAbove() ||isUnder()) {
        Point = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: `int Point = i;` is a typo, you need to drop the `int`.

Answer (score 1):

You could chain the conditions with the `||` operator:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (isLeft() || isRight() || isAbove() ||isUnder()) {
        Point = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not completely equivalent: if 'isUnder()' returns true the first time, and false the rest of the time, and 'isAbove()' returns true always, the original code will result in 'Point' being 0, while this new code will result in Point being 9.

Answer (score 1):

You can't merge the loops if you want the current control flow to be retained.

Currently:

1. All four functions run 10 times each
2. `isRight` will not be called until `isLeft` will no longer be called, etc.
3. `Point` is a stronger function of the result of `isUnder` than `isAbove`, etc.

You could consider using `||` within an `if` statement, but I think you are likely to introduce bugs, assuming of course that the code currently runs as intended.